# vue don't update a component apearance even after change are made to data

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, bootstrap-4

so, i got an issue with one of my vue component. my objective to have one image that is displayed by default, and after getting clicked it do some other action, and is suppossed to change

```
 <b-img v-else-if="isopen = true"  fluid src="someimage" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg" @click="opening()"></b-img>
 <b-img v-else-if="isopen = false" fluid src="someotherimage" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg"></b-img>
```

and there is the script part

```
    data () {
return {
  isopen: false,

}

    opening(){
//this function is called as intended
      console.log(this.isopen +'opening');
      this.isopen = false;
      console.log(this.isopen)
    }
```

everything in my code work fine, as debug prompt show that the state of `isopen` change as i want it too, but it don't update the displayed image. why don't it update itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo on conditions. It should be:

```
v-else-if="isopen == true"
v-else-if="isopen == false"
```

or simply

```
v-else-if="isopen"
v-else-if="!isopen"
```